# What is the meaning of "On Friday evening last"?

Tags: this-last

> On Friday evening last I received His Majesty's commission to form a new Administration.

This one is from Winston Churchill's speech: http://www.speeches-usa.com/Transcripts/winston_churchill-blood.html

It's also how the 5th book in the Red Rising series starts, which is where I first saw it.

Is this an unusual way of saying "at the end of the Friday's evening" or "on last Friday's evening"? Or does it mean something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In India some purists insist that we should say :

"He came here last Sunday".

```
       or
```

"He came here on Sunday last".

- He will come here next Sunday.
- He will come here on Sunday next.

The rule is the noun phrases such as *last Sunday* and *next Friday* should not follow the preposition "on." They should come at the end.

Examples from Google Books

> **ON Sunday last**, I called your attention to a subject, intimately
> connected with the happiness, which, as rational beings, ought to
> excite your deepest interest.
> *[A Series of Familiar Discourses for Every Sunday and Festival of the Year](https://books.google.it/books?id=MMBgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22on%20sunday%20last%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZnLu_2bTkAhUHGuwKHXFZBZ0Q6AEIUDAG#v=onepage&q=%22on%20sunday%20last%22&f=false)* (1827)

and

> June 27, 1810
> My very dear Friend,
> Brother Phanix will set off for London and Colchester **on Sunday next**, God willing, on the top of the Coach.
> *[The Letters of Dr. Thomas Coke](https://books.google.it/books?id=aA4H3PZjDXgC&pg=PA625&dq=%22on%20sunday%20next%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLsKCC27TkAhXHyqQKHe0nBcgQ6AEIVzAI#v=onepage&q=%22on%20sunday%20next%22&f=false)*

I do not know  whether native speakers still stick to this rule or not.

Comment: I’ve never thought about it before, but it’s true that I’d never say, “He came here on last Sunday.”  Instead I’d say, “He came here last Sunday.” or I’d add the date, “He came here on Sunday the twenty-third.”  In AmE nobody says “Sunday next/last”

Comment: @Mari-LouA. on last sunday.what proceeds what here?

Comment: The spelling is *pr**e**cede* not *proceed* they sound very similar but their meanings are different.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I think precede means come before and proceed means come after.Thank you for the edit

Comment: I think the edit by @Jim has confused the waters a bit. The words "Sunday last" and "Sunday next" in the examples taken from Google Books actually come **after** ( i.e. follow) the preposition "on". The OP was sayong these adverbial expressions should not come **before** I.e. precede "on".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I believe the question is about the words “next” and “ last” relative to the word “on”.  Without “on” one can say “next/last”: “I am meeting him next Sunday”  when “on” is used, the words “next/last” cannot follow it. They must be moved to the end:  “I am meeting him on Sunday next.”  That is how I understand OP’s intent.  I could have edited to keep “precede” by saying, “*last Sunday* should not be preceded by ‘on’...”  but I thought that was more complicated than it needed to be.  Didn’t mean to confuse.

Comment: @Jim what you thought was  correct.I am saying that on  should be followed  by sunday next  but not on  next sunday

Answer (score 4):

It's old style formal British  meaning "last Friday evening".